# Javascript Dice roll returns unidentified

Tags: javascript, dice

I am writting a dice roller for my website and thanks to my other question I can input data in my function but the Data I ask returns unidentified.

```
            //Constant
        var consDie = new Array(3); //Implanté les élément de constance des dés. 
            for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
                consDie[i] = 12 - (i * 2);
                console.log("D" + consDie[i]); 
            }

            var consNDice = 6; //Constante pour le nombre de dés
            var consAlign = {
                UnAl : consDie[2], 
                Bal : consDie[1], 
                Phys : consDie[0], 
                Ment : consDie[0]
            }; 
            //declaration of an object that contain the kind of dice that is rolled by powerup 

        //Variable integers
        var intDice = new Array(6); // contenant pour les résultats de dé.
        var intPhys = 0; //Phys Aligned answer counter
        var intBal = 0; //Neutral/balanced aligned answer counter
        var intMent = 0; //Mental aligned answer counter 


        //Dice Roll function

        function Dice (consAlign) {
            //Variables constant
            this.dicekind = consAlign;
            this.rollDice = function() {
                return Math.floor(Math.random()*dicekind);
            };

        }

        console.log(Dice(consAlign["Ment"]));
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: now I get NaN if I don't send a number in the () but I want the function to get my consAlign[] value ?

Comment: I've extended my answer to explain why you get NaN.

Comment: It works now! I am going to attack the "questionary" part of my code... I think I'll have to make JSon for that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dice` function does not return a value. It looks like you meant to use it to construct a new object:

```
console.log(new Dice(consAlign["Ment"]));
```

Edit: To follow up with your edit, you are getting `NaN` because `dicekind` is undefined. `5 * undefined` gives `NaN`, "Not a Number".

You would need to use `this.dicekind` inside `Dice` to make it work. Here's one way to do it work:

```
    function Dice(kind)
    {
        this._kind = kind;
    }

    Dice.prototype.roll = function()
    {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * this._kind) + 1;
    };

    var dice = new Dice(6);

    console.log(dice.roll());
```

I've also added 1 in the roll method so that the range of values is from 1..6, instead of 0..5.

Comment: ok I did that and it give me what the dice is supposed to be. `var nDice;
   nDice = new Dice(consAlign);
   console.log(nDice);`
It gives me an object with the Dice... now how do I roll that dice?

Comment: You can call the roll method: `nDice.rollDice()`. I've renamed it in my example to just `roll` since you already know that it is a `Dice` object, so you don't need to repeat that in the method name.

Comment: it helps a lot, I'm relearning JavaScript, been a long time I didn't code anything. I have to get back to pace!

Comment: `var nDice;
   nDice = new Dice(consAlign);
   console.log(nDice);
   for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
    intDice[i] = nDice.rollDice(nDice.dicekind["UnAl"]);
   }
   console.log(intDice);` I managed to make it work. So next step is to sort stuff out so I can make the game mechanic happen.